# CSS 3 tile effect

Tags: css

I'm developing a dashboard and I'm stuck at a place where I have to design a tile like effect. I tried using box-shadow and border properties but couldn't replicate the effect! Below is a sample image which shows the effect that I want! if any one has n idea on how to get this effect, please guide me!

thank you.

[image: Sample effect]

The code :

```
.header-tile{

    height: 90px;
    min-width: 60px;
    background-color: rgb(182, 163, 163);
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.64);
    margin: 0.5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);

}
```

Comment: *I tried using box-shadow and border properties but couldn't replicate the effect* **so where's the code**?

Comment: So how far did you get, and what's your html?

Comment: So that CSS produces a lovely pink div (http://jsfiddle.net/kxqqd/1/)? What part of this are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check this one. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/637Mz/)

```
.header-tile{

    height: 90px;
    min-width: 60px;
    background-color: rgb(182, 163, 163);
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .46), inset -1px -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .26);
    margin: 0.5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);

}
```

Is this what you want?

P.S.: You can set the value of opacity to work with the background color you choose for your tile.

Comment: yep! this is what I was looking for! than you!

Answer (score 0):

not entirely sure what your finding hard but all your colours were wrong:

```
.header-tile{

    height: 90px;
    min-width: 60px;
    background-color: #28272C;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.64);
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #454547;
    color:White;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kxqqd/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply making your shadows and border slightly thicker for a more pronounced effect? Using your CSS I made the following fiddle:

```
div {
    height: 150px;
    min-width: 150px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: rgb(182, 163, 163);
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 4px rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.8);
    margin: 0.5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MitulP91/3rv5V/3/)

I also altered the colors a little.